# Moving processed sql data into new table using c#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a lot of data in several tables that I am pulling from and combining into one view. I need to have a daily job using c# to pull all of this data then insert it into a separate database/table running on a different server. The data consists of some 150+ columns once combined and I don't want to use reader.read() reader.getstring() reader.etc for every column then combine it all into a string to insert again. Is there a way to just pass the results of an sql query to an insert in a simple and compact way?

```
private static void GetPrimaryData(string query)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(_awsOptionsDBConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32("tsid"));                      
                        }
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Ideally I'd just replace the Console.WriteLine(reader... part of code with some sort of insert where I pass the reader or the entire result of the reader query in.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the data comes directly from a database, or from a user, one still needs to send the data to a database in the structure the database defines.

Your question is asking for a *magical* converter which would work with any type of data and send it to any database. There is no such tool or library in C#/.Net.

---

One should look into a cloud solution that has already been developed such as Azure Data Factory or Informatica, etc.

Otherwise write the mappings/translations as needed in C# and use an ORM to send it the data to the database.

Comment: Mostly I'm looking for a way to send it as a data table. It seems I can define a table type in sql and call an insert command on that table type and send it a c# data table but I'm having issues creating a user defined table in our sql server.